# How to add email to my sign up but not login

Tags: android, android-studio, email, parsing, authentication

I've created a login/sign Up activity.In that I want to add an email option only for my sign up page but not for login page. I've made both in one single activity.

I'm using a parse server so i want to enter in it too just like username,so if possible inform me accordingly.

here is the code i've written:

```
      public void signUpClicked(View view) {

    if (usernameEditText.getText().toString().matches("") || passwordEditText.getText().toString().matches("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "A username, password and E-mail are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (signUpModeActive) {

            signUpModeActive = false;

            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(usernameEditText.getText().toString());
            user.setPassword(passwordEditText.getText().toString());

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.i("SignUp", "Success");
                        redirectUser();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernameEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Log.i("Login", "ok");
                        redirectUser();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm new to android studio.

Thanks....

Comment: Could you please provide more info and explain what actually you want?

Comment: I want to have a email option, like we have on usual sign up pages. but not have it on the login page and just have only username and password.

Comment: ok depending on the value of signUpModeActive will decide the type and display the screen accordingly.when you are changing the value of signUpModeActive change the visibility also.

Comment: Thanks... But that would be only concerning the layout. I would also like to know about the code and how to enter it into the parse dashboard column of email..